# Complex exponent in stationary state wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

A stationary state is defined to be an Eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian and its probability density function is simply a function of $x$. Since the pdf is the modulus squared of the wavefunction, does this mean that $\psi (x,t)$ cannot contain an imaginary exponent?

In addition, is a stationary state therefore never an eigenfunction of the momentum operator?

Could you also please explain the physical implications of this and the relation to the uncertainty principle (if applicable)?

Comment: What do you mean by $\psi(x,0)$ "containing" an imaginary exponent and how did you arrive at the thought that it's not an eigenfunction of momentum?

Comment: Sry I meant to write $\psi (x, t)$. What i meant by imaginary exponent was something like $Ae^(ikx)$. Also now that you say it doesn't really make sense that it shouldn't be an Eigenfunction of the momentum operator. So I guess that part is answered.

Comment: Actually no i remember: I learned that eigenfunctions of the momentum operator take the form $Ae^{ikx}$ or $Be^{-ikx}$ which means they cannot result in a probability density function thats dependent on $x$

Comment: To be clear, in the second paragraph, you're ruling out from consideration the eigenstates of a free particle?

Comment: No I dont think so, unless that is the definition of the stationary state

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking is what are the properties of $\psi (x)$ in the function $\psi (x,t) = \psi (x) e^{iEt/\hbar}$